# Scala - How to keep multiple values only once and remove other redundant values from a map

Tags: algorithm, scala, vector, collections

Given an input map as below:

```
val inputVal = Map(
  0 -> Vector(("a", (0,1)),("b",(0,2)),("a",(2,3)),("c",(1,1))),
  1 -> Vector(("a", (0,1)),("b",(0,2)),("d",(3,3)),("d",(4,3))),
  2 -> Vector(("d",(3,3)),("e",(1,3)))
)
```

I want to keep only once if the tuples  in the map values vectors are redundant or repeat in other element's value vectors of the inputVal map. so the output should be something like below

```
val output = Map(
  0 -> Vector(("a", (0,1)),("b",(0,2)),("a",(2,3)),("c",(1,1))),
  1 -> Vector(("d",(3,3)),("d",(4,3))),
  2 -> Vector(("e",(1,3)))
)
```

I tried with `diff()` but I need a different solution for this without using `diff`.

Comment: You can use a `foldLeft` to keep track of a `Set` of seen elements, or if you have **cats** in scope, you can use `mapAccumulate`

Comment: Maps aren't ordered. You should probably be using a `Seq` instead, since your keys seem to be just indices. Just iterate through that `Seq` keeping a global `Set` of tuples you have already, filter each vector to remove what's in the set, and add what's left to both the result and the set

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should iterate over the input, and for each entry, filter already used keys, and update the state in each iteration:

```scala
val (_, output) = inputVal
  .toSeq
  .sortBy(_._1)
  .foldLeft((Set.empty[String], Map.empty[Int, Vector[(String, (Int, Int))]])) {
    case ((alreadyUsedFields, acc), (mapKey, vec)) =>
      val entryKeysToKeep = vec.map(_._1).toSet.removedAll(alreadyUsedFields)
      alreadyUsedFields.union(entryKeysToKeep) -> acc.updated(mapKey, vec.filter(t => entryKeysToKeep.contains(t._1)))
  }
```

If you don't care about sorting, you can just omit the `toSeq` and `sortBy` lines.
Also, if you're sure that your map keys are always from 0 to `n`, you can do:

```scala
val (_, output) = (0 to n).foldLeft((Set.empty[String], Map.empty[Int, Vector[(String, (Int, Int))]])) {
    case ((alreadyUsedFields, acc), mapKey) =>
      val vec = inputVal(mapKey)
      val entryKeysToKeep = vec.map(_._1).toSet.removedAll(alreadyUsedFields)
      alreadyUsedFields.union(entryKeysToKeep) -> acc.updated(mapKey, vec.filter(t => entryKeysToKeep.contains(t._1)))
  }
```

As a matter of preference, I wouldn't go for the second approach, but it should produce the same output.